# Third party survey onto popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a third party survey onto a popup and it's not working. Where am I making a mistake?

This should happen on a click a button or href. So I am creating a iframe dynamically.

```
$('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" width="400" height="400">').appendTo('body');
```

then loading the data to it..

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var script = myIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/2296429/Advertisement-Feedback?_output=embedjs"
myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I am interested in any other ideas to achieve this; I cannot make a ajax call as it is going to complain about the cross domain thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your console for error messages, you will see:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Which means that you have a "<" somewhere in your javascript where it should not be.

Now, navigate to `https://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/2296429/Advertisement-Feedback?_output=embedjs`

Note that the is an `html` file which you are trying to load into a `script` tag.

**Change your code to this:**

```js
$('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" width="400" height="400">').appendTo('body');

var myIframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
myIframe.src = "https://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/2296429/Advertisement-Feedback?_output=embedjs"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its is working for you? its not loading the content for me on to iframe, can you try in jsFiddle or so

Comment: i am getting some security error on chrome, let me try on firefox

Comment: Thank you very much, if i want to show this as popup, i can simple append this iframe to a div and position abosulte right?

Comment: Sure. With a high z-index, if you plan to use bootstrap 3 at all, I'd throw it in a modal for style and functionality purposes.